# Set up spf and dkim, where email domain and sending domain differ

Tags: spam, g-suite, spf, dkim

I have two domains:

`foo.com` and `bar.com`

Only `foo.com` is using `Google Apps` and thus can send emails. I now have a service running on `bar.com\application` that uses the email `application@foo.com` to send emails to others. However, all the mails get delivered to the spam folder of the recipient.
I checked the header and it says

```
spf=neutral (google.com: 2607:f8b0:4001:c02::2ef is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of application@foo.com
```

Therefore I would like to set up a `spf` record. Now I don't know for which domain I have to set the `spf`. Do I have to set it for `foo.com`, because the mails get send with that domain or do I have to set it in `bar.com`, because that's where the mail get send from?

In addition, I heard setting up a `DKIM` entry in the nameserver is recommended as well, but does this make sense in my case? As far as I understand, `DKIM` verifies that a mail is in fact coming from the domain/IP, which uses the mail service (`foo.com` in my case). That, however, would mean sending from `bar.com` using `application@foo.com` would be bad, because it didn't get send from `bar.com`?

Answer (score 1):

SPF records are setup for the domain of the email being sent. In your example, the email "sender" is application@foo.com so the SPF record needs to be in foo.com's DNS.

The idea is any recipient will look up the DNS records for the sender of email it has received to confirm it is originating from an approved mail server. In your case, the recipient would look up bar.com's mail server to see if it is an approved outgoing mail server for foo.com.

Based on the IPv6 address you listed, foo.com's SPF record would be:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip6:2607:f8b0:4001:c02::2ef ~all
```

DKIM provides a greater level of SPAM resistance but it is not necessary in my experience.

Comment: DKIM will generate a hash from some of the email headers, when receiving this email, the receiving side will look up the key on the sender's DNS server (foo.com on your case) and use that to decrypt and 'checksum' the header. So if you setup the signing keys on your bar.com server, you can sign email for foo.com and use DKIM. Yahoo is particularly fond of DKIM. I would start with the SPF and implement DKIM if I still had issues after that.